# Print values on Paraview from C

Tags: c, csv, paraview

and I need help (again).

My problem is as follow:

**1**.- I need to print the values of a volume using ParaView.
**2**.- I save the values with coordinates and intensities and a file **.Csv**.

i,j,k,Intensity

0,0,0,0.000000

0,1,0,0.000000

0,2,0,0.000000

0,3,0,0.000000

0,4,0,0.000000

0,5,0,0.000000

etc...

**3**.- But What I get is:
[image: Screen of ParaView]

**4**.- I know Paraview use a lot of format, but I need to print the values of volume with data obtained from language C(not c++).

**5**.-  Finally the true question... Can I use this kind of file (csv) to print a volume or I need to change to other? Because I don't have idea how to make RAW o TVK... can you help me please?

Ivan.

Comment: To paraphrase your paraview question: "Can I read a CSV file from C, and then perform math on what I've read?"

The answer to that is YES. Now, if you want us to show you how, you'll have to show us yours first... :)

Comment: I don't see anything cuda related so I'm removing the cuda tag.

Comment: Hi, this values I obtained using CUDA to solve a heat equation in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Mats Petersson, sorry I did not understand your paraphrase, I need to know if it is possible to print a volume with the extension cvs. I got coordinates but just appears points I need cubes or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, I am not to sure if I understand you but you can use the

"Table To Structured Grid" filter, then you can represent it as a Volume and color by the intensity scalar field.